# Why Button has to be wrap with CardActions in MUI

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I was reading the [Card documentation](https://mui.com/components/cards/) on MUI and notice the Button in the card is always wrapped with CardActions, and I don't know really understand what that tag serves as it doesn't really explained in the documentation. Only noticeble attributes on their [API](https://mui.com/api/card-actions/) and while I was playing is disableSpacing, which disable the margin and spacing between the buttons. The similar tag, CardActionArea makes more sense as it turns component in the Card to be interactive and it inherits ButtonBase, but CardActions only inherits native component. Is there more to this tag that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in the docs does it say that it *has* to be wrapped with `CardActions`. `CardHeader`, `CardContent`, `CardActions`, `CardMedia`, and `CardActionArea` are just inner convenience containers with preset settings to organize things inside the card according to Material's design vision. The main differences are seen in the padding and spacing. `CardAction` has a padding of 1 (8px), `CardContent` 2 (16px), `CardMedia` 0. And the spacing inside `CardAction` is 2 vs `CardContent` 1.

If your design doesn't need the convenience of these containers, it's perfectly ok to use `Button` by itself. Though in that case why use the `Card` component at all; just use the simpler `Paper` component instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was looking at the Card because the codebase I was working were wrapping Button with CardAction and was wondering what the functionality was. I think your suggestion with switching to Paper is a good idea. Thank you for the suggestion.